# How to query by Id and by Boolean set to "True" using Spring Data JPA

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

In my Spring Repository (CRUD) I want to bypass the @Query annotation and query using Spring Data JPA Query Creation and `Entity` by its Id and where a `boolean : Deleted` of it is set to `false`. I tried :

```
ReturnType findByIdAndDeletedFalse(@Param("id") Long id)
```

My question is : is it possible to write it that way to do the query ?
I am using MongoDB,

Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

`IsFalse` is a repository query keyword and so you can use `findByIdAndDeletedIsFalse`